# Retrieving data from SQLite and displaying in Listview

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I am trying to display the contents of my mysqlite database into a listview,
I am able to get the contents and display them in a textview, but for some 
reason I can't add the details to an arraylist ? I am not too sure what am doing 
wrong. I have looked for multiple solutions but none of them seem to work, am getting an error

> Android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsExecption: Index requested -1

Here is what I currently have:

OnCreate:

```
    ArrayAdapter<Contact> currentContactsAdapter = new ContactArrayAdapter();

    ListView lvcontacts = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvContacts);

    lvcontacts.setAdapter(currentContactsAdapter);

    tdb = new TestDBOpenHelper(this, "contact.db", null, 1);
    sdb = tdb.getWritableDatabase();

    new MyContacts().execute();
```

ListView Adapter:

```
private class ContactArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contact>{

    public ContactArrayAdapter(){
        super(MainActivity.this, R.layout.listviewitem, addedContacts);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View itemView = convertView;
        if(itemView == null){
            itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.listviewitem, parent, false);
        }

        Contact currentContact = addedContacts.get(position);       

        TextView name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvNameitem);
        name.setText(currentContact.getName());

        TextView phone = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPhoneitem);
        phone.setText(currentContact.getPhone());

        TextView email = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvEmailitem);
        email.setText(currentContact.getEmail());

        return itemView;
    }
}
```

GetContacts:

```
class MyContacts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    List<Contact> retrievedContacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();

protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        String cname;
        String cphone;
        String cemail;

        // name of the table to query
        String table_name = "contact";
        // the columns that we wish to retrieve from the tables
        String[] columns = {"FIRST_NAME", "PHONE", "EMAIL"};
        // where clause of the query. DO NOT WRITE WHERE IN THIS
        String where = null;
        // arguments to provide to the where clause
        String where_args[] = null;
        // group by clause of the query. DO NOT WRITE GROUP BY IN THIS
        String group_by = null;
        // having clause of the query. DO NOT WRITE HAVING IN THIS
        String having = null;
        // order by clause of the query. DO NOT WRITE ORDER BY IN THIS
        String order_by = null;
        // run the query. this will give us a cursor into the database
        // that will enable us to change the table row that we are working with
        Cursor c = sdb.query(table_name, columns, where, where_args, group_by, 
        having, order_by);

        for(int i  = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++) {
            cname  =  c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("FIRST_NAME"));
            cphone =  c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("PHONE"));
            cemail =  c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("EMAIL"));
            c.moveToNext();
            retrievedContacts.add(new Contact(cname,cphone,cemail));
        }

        return null;
    }

//Update Contact list when response from server is received 
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    for(Contact contact: retrievedContacts)
        addedContacts.add(contact);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your table "contact" doesn't have the exact structure you are trying to read.

> Android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsExecption: Index requested -1

This means that one of these column names is not part of it.

```
c.getColumnIndex("FIRST_NAME") 
c.getColumnIndex("PHONE")
c.getColumnIndex("EMAIL")
```

So one of them return `-1` instead of the index because they not exist in the table.

EDIT:

Then the `for` loop may be faulty. I suggest to use something like:

```
if (c != null ) {
    if  (c.moveToFirst()) { // Always move at the first item
        do {
            cname  =  c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("FIRST_NAME"));
            cphone =  c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("PHONE"));
            cemail =  c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("EMAIL"));
            retrievedContacts.add(new Contact(cname, cphone, cemail));
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
}
c.close(); // always close when done!
```

Comment: Here is the database i created.
    `private static final String create_table = "create table contact(" +
 "ID integer primary key autoincrement, " +
 "FIRST_NAME string," +
 "PHONE string, " +
 "EMAIL string" +
 ")";` 
plus when i try this on another activity it works like i can display the contents in a textView

Comment: That's quite tricky. I edit my post with another suggestion. Also you can try to run the debugger to see exactly where the code brakes or add some logs to see what happens inside the for loop.

Comment: I was missing the 'c.moveToFirst()' it works now ty ^^